# How to create a table-like structure that I can fill in with values

Tags: powerbi

I've got a table in Excel that looks something like this

[image]

and I'm trying to recreate it in Power BI.

So far, the approach I'm using is I'm creating individual text boxes, assigning measures to them, and putting them together in a way that looks like the table in the picture.

My question is, is there a better way to do this? Is there a way I could create that table format (having everything be blank) and then start to assign measures to each section of the table? If this is possible, what tool could I use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You apparently need a Matrix, a standard visual.

For your particular sample table, you also need a column "somewhere" in your data model that contains the distinct values `1 week`,  `1 month` and `MTD`. Since these are rows in your sample table they must be present as a column in your model.

### Give me a solution I can implement right off the bat

The most straightforward way to do this is to add a datatable with these options:

```
Time slices =
DATATABLE (
    "Slice", STRING,
    "Sort", INTEGER,
    {
        { "1 Week", 1 },
        { "1 Month", 2 },
        { "MTD", 3 }
    }
)
```

You can use the `Sort` column in this table to apply sort order for the `Slice` column.

Your measures should look like this, which picks up the row time slice designation in the visual, and does calculations differently based on which category is being evaluted. I.e. you have many ways of calculating the same Measure, depending on which `Slice` value you are evaluating it for :

```
Attempts =
VAR _slice =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Time slices'[Slice] )
VAR _lastdate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date] )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        _slice = "1 Week",
            CALCULATE (
                COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),
                DATESBETWEEN ( 'Table'[Date], _lastdate - 6, _lastdate )
            ),
        _slice = "1 Month",  /* simplified */
            CALCULATE (
                COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),
                DATESBETWEEN ( 'Table'[Date], _lastdate - 30, _lastdate ) 
            ),
        _slice = "MTD", 
            CALCULATE ( 
                COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),  
                DATESMTD ( 'Table'[Date] ) 
            )
    )
```

### Other options?

The more robust way would be to introduce a calendar table in your data model, and one additional table (for slicing your calendar table) that contains two columns; `Date` and `Time slice`, with one row per valid date per time slice (7 rows for `1 week` etc.). You connect this table to the calendar table with a one-way filtering many-many relationship, so that `Time slice` filters `Calendar`, but not the other way around.

In this data model you use the `Time slice` column as rows in your matrix, and the use of this column will infer the correct set of dates in the calculation by using a way simpler measure:

```
Attempts = COUNTROWS ( 'Table' )
```

Doing it this way represents more overhead before you start seeing results, but makes for way easier control of what your measures calculate, easier to debug if you see issues, and so on. However, it does require more knowledge (calendar tables, and generating "dimension tables" for calendar tables).